# Dygraph date plotting over JSON

Tags: javascript, json, dygraphs

Using a JSON post call, I can format the data set to return
['2009/07/12 12:34:56, 100']  but dygraphs documentations says

[ new Date("2009/07/12"), 100] (Taken from [here](http://dygraphs.com/data.html))

This is very unfortunate, I cannot send a date object since there will be automatic conversions. I'm working with around 2 million data, and it is very slow to for-loop [new Date('2009/07/12 12:34:56), 100'] 2 million times.
The efficiency will be much greater if taken straight from a JSON call.

Is there anyway to plot dates without client side modifications?/ straight from a JSON call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't transmit Dates as JSON, since they're [not supported](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Unsupported_native_data_types) in the JSON spec.

An alternative would be to transmit milliseconds since epoch, which is how dygraphs represents these values internally. You'll have to manually set the various x-axis options if you do this. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/4848/):

```js
g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById('graph'),
    [[1247382000000, 10],
     [1247468400000, 20],
     [1247554800000, 30]],
    {
        labels: ['Date', 'Value'],
        axes: {
            x: {
                valueFormatter: Dygraph.dateString_,
                axisLabelFormatter: Dygraph.dateAxisFormatter,
                ticker: Dygraph.dateTicker
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is the fiddle related?

Comment: whoops! fixed the link.

Comment: It worked, just got to figure out the way to convert to milliseconds since epoch. EDIT - Perfect! The performance increased insanely. Thank you.